# UseEffect showing inappropriate value, but only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to print the value of the state `value` whenever I change the password (using **useEffect** hook). Although it's working well, whenever I try to change the `email`, the value of `email` is also rendering in the console

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
  }, [values.password]);
```

but as per my logic should be only rendered whenever the value of `password` is changed.

Following is the log
[image]

As I marked they must not be shown as they are rendering whenever I change the value of `email`

Following is my code

**Form.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useForm = (initialValues) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    values,
    (e) => {
      setValues({
        //...values,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    },
  ];
};
```

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "./Form";

const App = () => {
  const [values, handelChange] = useForm({ email: "", password: "" });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
  }, [values.password]);

  return (
    <div className="field">
      <input
        type="email"
        name="email"
        value={values.email}
        onChange={handelChange}
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handelChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: why did you comment this line out: `//...values,`?

Comment: Because currently I don't want the previous values to be passed on

Comment: But you are aware that when you change `password: "Pass"` to `undefined`, that's also a change of `[values.password]` so `useEffect` gets triggered.

Comment: @Thomas it means where I try to change the value of email the value of password is set to `undefined|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you have to change is removing the commented `values`-destructoring at your `useForm`-hook:

```js
  return [
    values,
    (e) => {
      setValues({
        ...values, // remove the comment from your code in the question!!
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    },
  ];
};
```

The comment causes, that password is removed (you can call the prop `password` on values, but you get `undefined`) from the new `values`-object on every email-input. In the log, you see that, but as you described, **only once**!

Furthermore, I would change your `useForm`-hook to:

```js
const useForm = (initialValues) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    values,
    (e) => {
      setValues(prevValues => {
        return {
          ...prevValues,
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        }
      });
    }
  ];
};
```

If the new state is computed using the previous state, you should use the previous state from params. React state updates can be batched, and not writing your updates this way can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks I will take care of it from next time.